# Namespace selector with jquery not possible after update jquery after version 1.7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, namespaces

I tried selecting namespaced elements with jquery like this:

```
var $svg = $('svg');
var $elements = $('a[xlink\\|href]', $svg);  // Select only a xlink attributes inside svg object
var $allelements = $('a[*|href]', $svg);  // Select all a href attributes inside svg object
```

With jquery v1.7.2 this worked. With later versions (v1.8.3 and higher) this did not work anymore. Does anybody know how I can select a namespaced attribute with jquery now.? Or is this a bug in jquery ?

example svg:
    https://jsfiddle.net/frontendplace/wytfoq3q/

Comment: Only `$allelements` should find something. I guess that for the first one you meant `a[xlink\\:href]`. (Can't test right now for the jQuery issue though).

Answer (score 1):

For `$elements` you can use `.filter()`, `attributes` `.getNamedItem()` with parameter `"xlink:href"`; for `$allelements` you can use `$("a[href]", $svg);`

```js
var $svg = $("svg");
// Select only a xlink attributes inside svg object
var $elements = $("a", $svg).filter(function() {
  return this.attributes.getNamedItem("xlink:href") !== null
});
// Select all a href attributes inside svg object
var $allelements = $("a[href]", $svg);

console.log("svg", $svg);
console.log("elements", $elements, $elements[0]);
console.log("all elements", $allelements, $allelements[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="5cm" height="3cm" viewBox="0 0 5 3">
  <desc>Example link01 - a link on an ellipse
  </desc>
  <rect x=".01" y=".01" width="4.98" height="2.98" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width=".03" />
  <a xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.w3.org">
    <ellipse cx="2.5" cy="1.5" rx="2" ry="1" fill="red" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">anchor</a>
</svg>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wytfoq3q/3/

Comment: I still can't test, but your HTMLAnchor in the svg makes your svg invalid. SVGAnchor can't have textNode just like that.

Comment: @Kaiido _"your HTMLAnchor in the svg makes your svg invalid"_? Did not compose `svg`. Only posted as to selecting elements. What needs to be changed?

Comment: Ah I see it was in OP's code. The textNode should at least be wrapped in an SVGText (`<text>`) element.

Comment: @Kaiido Updated stacksnippets to include `<text>` inside of `<a>`

Comment: Thanx this answers my question